# Strange grep prime testing result

Tags: regex, grep, primes

The following four results illustrate what I mean by "strange":

```
> printf "%11s" | tr " " "1" | grep -E '^1?$|^(11+)\1+$'
11111111111
> printf "%10s" | tr " " "1" | grep -E '^1?$|^(11+)\1+$'
1111111111
> printf "%11s" | tr " " "1" | grep -E '^(11+)\1+$'
> printf "%10s" | tr " " "1" | grep -E '^(11+)\1+$'
1111111111
>
```

The pattern supplied to grep is for prime testing, and grep should fail when supplied with a prime number of 1's. The third and fourth calls 'work', but when the optional part of the grep pattern is included (i.e. in the first and second calls), the grep incorrectly matches against a prime number of 1's. Why?

I am using Ubuntu and the bash shell.

Comment: This is just how POSIX regex works. You need a PCRE regex here, and this will work for you since you are on Ubuntu: `grep -P '^1?$|^(11+)\1+$'`

Comment: The problem only appears when I add the OR to the pattern, which is not a PCRE feature.